# Shape information lost when using arcpy Polyline object as dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, arcgis, shapefile, arcpy

Environment: Win 7 Enterprise, SP1 | ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 (Python 2.6.5)

I am attempting to store Arcpy Polyline objects as values in a Python dictionary so that they can be quickly referenced in a data comparison tool.

Problem: 
Once my script exits a FOR loop used to save Polyline objects to a dictionary, all the Polyline objects in the Python dictionary have the same properties (they should all be different). Each of the functions below creates five distinct Polyline objects in memory, however, the properties for the ReadData1 objects are all different while the properties for the ReadData2 objects are all the same.

Question:
Why are the Polyline object properties (.firstPoint .centroid .lastPoint) correct immediately after assigning them as dictionary values but incorrect after the FOR loop completes? Specifically, why are the properties for the final Polyline object from the ReadData1 output associated with all objects in the ReadData2 output?

Code:

```
import arcpy

def ReadData1(inShapefile):
    print arcpy.Describe(inShapefile).dataType, arcpy.Describe(inShapefile).shapeType
    sRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inShapefile)
    dataDict = {}
    for row in sRows:
            dataDict[row.FID] = row.Shape
            print '%s || %s || %s' % (dataDict[row.FID].firstPoint, dataDict[row.FID].centroid, dataDict[row.FID].lastPoint)

def ReadData2(inShapefile):
    print arcpy.Describe(inShapefile).dataType, arcpy.Describe(inShapefile).shapeType
    sRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inShapefile)
    dataDict = {}
    for row in sRows:
            dataDict[row.FID] = row.Shape
    for key in dataDict:
            print '%s || %s || %s' %(dataDict[key].firstPoint, dataDict[key].centroid, dataDict[key].lastPoint)
```

Output:

```
>>> ReadData1(r'U:\...\TestShapefile.shp')
ShapeFile Polyline
7590284.40892474 668332.064064309 NaN NaN || 7590324.42908373 666711.247624955 NaN NaN || 7592576.19984799 665145.042311657 NaN NaN
7592021.15673377 667418.928618325 NaN NaN || 7592961.14910463 667427.880926619 NaN NaN || 7593901.1414755 667436.833234913 NaN NaN
7594098.09225797 668421.587147249 NaN NaN || 7595183.14682072 667013.998170435 NaN NaN || 7596891.21244568 665682.180809295 NaN NaN
7593793.71377597 665897.03620835 NaN NaN || 7593516.19221886 665261.422319479 NaN NaN || 7593238.67066174 664625.808430607 NaN NaN
7590302.31354132 663336.676036276 NaN NaN || 7593453.20916493 663528.873380711 NaN NaN || 7596533.12011392 663873.814533914 NaN NaN

>>> ReadData2(r'U:\...\TestShapefile.shp')
ShapeFile Polyline
7590302.31354132 663336.676036276 NaN NaN || 7593453.20916493 663528.873380711 NaN NaN || 7596533.12011392 663873.814533914 NaN NaN
7590302.31354132 663336.676036276 NaN NaN || 7593453.20916493 663528.873380711 NaN NaN || 7596533.12011392 663873.814533914 NaN NaN
7590302.31354132 663336.676036276 NaN NaN || 7593453.20916493 663528.873380711 NaN NaN || 7596533.12011392 663873.814533914 NaN NaN
7590302.31354132 663336.676036276 NaN NaN || 7593453.20916493 663528.873380711 NaN NaN || 7596533.12011392 663873.814533914 NaN NaN
7590302.31354132 663336.676036276 NaN NaN || 7593453.20916493 663528.873380711 NaN NaN || 7596533.12011392 663873.814533914 NaN NaN
```

Test Shapefile:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67329940/TestShapefile.zip

ESRI Polyline object documentation:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000n2000000

Thanks!

Comment: I found this: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/61119-can-you-explain-what-is-happening-here?p=262460#post262460 but it doesn't provide a clear solution - perhaps it's time to upgrade Arcpy.

Answer (score 2):

You've run into a known issue with ArcGIS 10.0.  It's fixed in 10.1, which is what I'm using now.  But I used to get around the issue on 10.0 by converting the shape to a list, and then re-creating it like so:

```
tractfc = 'c:/temp/test.shp'

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(tractfc)
dct = {}
for row in rows:
    shp = row.Shape
    lst = list(shp)
    ary = arcpy.Array(lst)
    newshp = arcpy.Polyline(ary, shp.spatialReference)
    dct[row.FID] = newshp

for k in dct:
    print k, dct[k].firstPoint
```

You can use a geojson conversion with `__geo_interface__` and rebuilding with AsShape, but you lose your spatial reference that way.  The method above preserves the spatial reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set an arcpy.Geometry() to store your row.Shape otherwise you will lost the geometry. here an example from the code above.

```
tractfc = 'c:/temp/test.shp' 
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(tractfc)
dct = {}

for row in rows:
   g = arcpy.Geometry()
   g = row.Shape
   dct[row.FID] = g

for k in dct:
   print k, dct[k].firstPoint.X, dct[k].firstPoint.Y
```